# C++ - create new constructor for std::vector<double>?

Tags: c++

I have written a custom container class which contains a `std::vector<double>` instance - works nicely. For compatibility with other API's I would like to export     the content of the container as a `std::vector<double>` copy . Currently this works:

```
MyContainer container;
....
std::vector<double> vc(container.begin(), container.end());
```

But if possible would like to be able to write:

```
MyContainer container;
....
std::vector<double> vc(container);
```

Can I (easily) create such a `std::vector<double>` constructor?

Comment: Thank you for all suggestions; I learned about the 'cast operator' - today; however I generally prefer explicit to implicit so I have accepted the answer from @Madame Elyse

Comment: Despite what the answers say, there is no such thing as a "cast operator". They're talking about a "**conversion** operator", whose job is simply to provide a conversion from one type to another. A **cast** is something you write in your code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. That's a **explicit** conversion. The compiler can also do some conversions without seeing a cast. That's an **implicit** conversion. When you mark a conversion operator as `explicit` you restrict the circumstances in which the compiler can use it, and often that ends up requiring a cast.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can create an explicit conversion to `std::vector<double>`:

```
explicit operator std::vector<double>() const {
    return std::vector<double>(begin(), end());
}
```

Then, `std::vector<double> vc(container);` will invoke the `std::vector<double>` move constructor.

Note that conversions that are computationally expensive are generally frowned upon. Therefore, a vector factory function may be a wiser approach:

```
class MyContainer {
public:
    using value_type = double;
    // ...
};

template<typename Source>
auto to_vector(Source source) {
    return std::vector<typename Source::value_type>(source.begin(), source.end());
}
```

Then you'd write:

```
MyContainer container;
// ...
auto vc = to_vector(container);
```

This is also more generic as it works with anything that has compatible `value_type`, `begin` and `end` members.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I (easily) create such a std::vector constructor?

No you can't, since this would require to change the `std::vector` class declarations.

You can provide a cast operator for `MyContainer` to `std::vector<double>` though.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, and should not, change the API of a class you didn't write yourself.  But I think in your case a cast operator would do just fine.  For example (this one needs `-std=c++11`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Foo
{
  operator std::vector<double> () const
  {
    return std::vector<double> { 1, 2, 3 };
  }
};

int main()
{
  Foo foo;
  std::vector<double> bar = foo; // Applies the cast operator defined in Foo
  std::cout << bar.size() << std::endl; // Prints "3"
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain why it's bad, and why it's wrong?

Comment: Well covered on the other answers & comments. Heavy implicit conversions like this cause bugs.

Comment: The chosen answer suggests `explicit`, but does not say why. Personally I'd say it depends very much on the use case whether or not it's a good idea to allow implicit conversion. After all, there is a reason why an `explicit` keyword exists in the first place. I can see why it _can_ be a bad idea, but that doesn't generalize. Also, “bad” is not the same as “wrong”.

Comment: `explicit` was added because default-implicit operators were a mistake. [We don't like non-trivial implicit conversions any more](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060524-12/?p=31083). And "bad and wrong" is an idiom.